# Install Restler problems

Tags: php, web-services, frameworks, installation, restler

Hi everyone i just have tried to understand how to install Restler to create a PHP web service but i can't did it. I don't understand the manual(https://github.com/Luracast/Restler), i just have install the composer and now i don't know what i having to do. I think i have to run in command some thing but i don't know and where i have to put the files that i have downloaded? In project folder or xampp folder? If anyone can help me i will appreciate.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

**Install Composer Globally**

1. install composer.phar into the PHP folder (where php.exe lives)
2. set the PHP folder on Environment path
3. execute on the windows command line: `php composer.phar`

   - composer should show up and now you know its available
   - what you now have is a "[composer global installation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally) on windows"

**Setup application and define it's dependencies (manually)**

1. create application folder, for your upcoming application which uses restler
2. add a composer.json file, this file describes all the packages your application uses

   - one of these packages is RESTLER, add it in the require setion
3. now execute `php composer.phar install` to install these dependencies
4. then inspect the folder `/vendor` to find restler
5. to use it in your application, simply require the composer autoloader

   - `require APP_DIR . '/vendor/autoload.php';`

**Basic composer.json**

`{
    "name":"developer/application",
    "require": {
        "luracast/restler": "*"
    }
}`

**This is the easiest way to install it:**

```
php.exe composer.phar create-project luacrest/restler targetFolder
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Install composer
2. Move composer.phar to (xampp path)htdocs
3. You can follow tutorial  to install restler